# How to do MCMC simulation using Metropolis hasting algorithm in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, montecarlo, markov-chains, beta-distribution

I am trying to simulate a distribution for parameter theta `f= theta ^(z_f+n+alpha-1)*(1-theta)^(n+1-z_f-k+ beta-1)`, where all the parameter except for theta is know. I am using Metro polish hasting algorithm to do the MCMC simulation . My proposal density is a beta distribution with parameter alpha and beta. My code for the simulation are as follows. I am using a buitlin Matlab code called mhsample() for this purpose, How do I know if my code is working properly?

```
clear
clc
alpha=2;
beta=2;
z_f=1;
n=6;
k=5;

nsamples = 3000;
pdf= @(x) x^(z_f+n+alpha-1)*(1-x)^(n+1-z_f-k+beta-1); % here x acts as theta
proppdf= @(x,y) betapdf(x, alpha, beta);
proprnd =@(x) betarnd(alpha,beta,1);

smpl = mhsample(0.1,nsamples,'pdf',pdf,'proprnd',proprnd,'proppdf',proppdf);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of what you're asking when you say "how do I know if my code is working properly" -- I'm assuming it executes? But for a visual comparison of your function vs. the simulation, you can plot both the PDF and the data you got from mhsample as follows:

```
% i'm assuming you ran the code above so that smpl and @pdf are both defined...

fplot(pdf,[0 1]); % fplot takes your function and plots it between x-limit [0,1]
figure % new figure
hist(smpl,30); % 30 here is bin size, change it to your preference
```

Figure below:

- the histogram of `smpl`'s output on left, i.e., your simulation
- the function `pdf` bounded in [0,1] on right for comparison to your simulation

[image: output of smpl on left, pdf bounded in [0,1] on right]

This was just a wild guess because those two figures resemble each other and are also beta-distribution-esque.

If you want a more complex analysis than that, I'm afraid I'm not yet proficient in MCMC :)

Comment: By "how do I know if my code is working properly" , I meant is there any logical error in the way I am entering arguments in the function "proppdf()" and "proprnd()"?